# Apache Spark Ec2: could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a 2Node cluster running on Ec2 d2.xlarge instance, and i have a 10 Gb of file to be processed through Spark, I have mounted a local Disk on spark and generated the Dataset o 10gb over there, but when I am trying to put that into Hdfs its throwing me the error of **"could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1"**   as follows

```
16/03/09 21:44:25 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /vinit/inputfile.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Comment: Your HDFS datanodes are not working. Check their logs.

Comment: Yes i checked that using jps command, but how do I configure and start it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your HDFS datanodes are not working and you have checked with `jps` command. You can configure the datanodes(slaves) by adding hostname or IP entries of datanodes to `<HADOOP_HOME>/etc/hadoop/slaves` file e.g.:

```
192.168.64.11
192.168.64.12
```

and similary for namenode (master) you can add entires to `<HADOOP_HOME>/etc/hadoop/masters` file e.g.: (assuming 192.168.64.11 is the master)

```
192.168.64.11
```

then run stop-all.sh and star-all.sh on master-node to restart the cluster. This will automatically start the datanodes. Check with jps command.

Comment: I exactly followed you steps, but its not working. I managed to start the datanode using ./hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode command. and tried putting my file to the directory i mounted on ec2 using ./hadoop fs -put /newDir/inputfile.txt   /newDir/dir. But getting the same exception.

Comment: Before submitting hadoop job first check the status of cluster either using browser `http://name-node-ip:50070/` or on console `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hdfs  dfsadmin -report` and any node not started then check the latest log of that node.